# funky file name output from shell/bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So, im making a small script to do an entire task for me. The task is to get the output of the **`dmidecode -Fn`** into a text file and then take a part of the **`dmidecode`** output, in my example, the Address (0xE0000) as the file name of the txt.

My script goes as follows and does work, i have tested it. The only little issue that i have, is that the file name of the txt appears as "*? 0xE0000.txt*"

My question is, why am i getting a question mark followed by a space in the name?

```
#!/bin/bash
directory=$(pwd)
name=$(dmidecode|grep -i Address|sed 's/Address://')
inxi -Fn > $directory/"$name".txt
```

The quotes in the **`"$name".txt`** is to avoid an "ambiguous redirect" error i got when running the script.

**Update @Just Somebody**

```
root@server:/home/user/Desktop# dmidecode | sed -n 's/Address://p'
         0xE0000
root@server:/home/user/Desktop#
```

**Solution**
The use of `|sed -n 's/^.*Address:.*0x/0x/p'` got rid of the "? " in 0xE0000.txt

A big thanks to everyone!

Comment: What does `echo "$name" | xxd` output?

Comment: Sounds like `dmicode` is putting something between `Address:` and the address. Maybe a TAB character?

Comment: If I had to take a stab in the dark, I've had cases of `grep` inserting color escape sequences and breaking things.  Make sure you don't have `grep` aliased or be explicit and use `grep --color=never`

Comment: *My script goes as follows and does work, i have tested it.* -- that's a bold statement given the `dmicode` typo.

Comment: `grep | sed` is always suspicious and rarely warranted, sed is usually enough.  in your case, `dmidecode | sed -n '/Address://p'`

Comment: yea, the demicode is a typo in my post and is supposed to be demidecode. Thank you for pointing that out :). Also, if im correct, you suggested to test `dmidecode | sed -n '/Address://p'` - this gives me error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown command '/'`

Comment: @EtanReisner
That gives me a giant name of `0000000 \t 0 x E 0 0 0 0 \n 0000012 `

Comment: @xR34P3Rx typo, use `sed -n 's/Address://p'`

Comment: @xR34P3Rx so you *do* have a tab (`\t`) character in there.  your grep is badly misconfigured, it shouldn't use colors when the output is not the terminal.  which it isn't when you pipe the output into something else, like sed.

Comment: ill put the exact output of my command ran in terminal when i single out the Address, it does have a space before the `0xE0000`

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using python-dmidecode rather than upstream dmidecode at all -- that way you're able to retrieve the data you want without needing to parse it out of an ASCII stream (avoiding the assumptions you're currently making about behavior that isn't guaranteed to persist unmodified in future versions).

Comment: By the way -- editing a solution into a question is bad form. If you want to accept someone's solution, click the checkbox next to it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a nonprinting char in there. Try:

```
dmidecode |grep -i Address|sed 's/Address://'| od -c
```

to see exactly what you're getting.

**UPDATE:** comments indicate there's a tab char in there that needs to be cleaned out.

**UPDATE 2**: the leading tab is *before* the word `Address`. Try:

```
name=$(dmidecode |grep -i Address|sed 's/^.*Address:.*0x/0x/')
```

or as @just_somebody points out:

```
name=$(dmidecode|sed -n 's/^.*Address:.*0x/0x/p')
```

**UPDATE 3**

This changes the substitution regex to replace

^ (start of line) followed by .* (any characters (including tab!)) followed by Address: followed by .* (any characters (including space!)) followed by 0x (which are always at the beginning of the address since it's in hex)

with

0x (because you want that as part of the result)

If you want to learn more, read about sed regular expressions and substitutions.

Comment: typing this directly into terminal gives me:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 13: unknown option to `s'
0000000`

Comment: Sorry, typo'd an extra / in there. Edited.

Comment: thought so, what i get now is 0000000 \t      0   x   E   0   0   0   0 \n  0000012

Comment: @pjz drop the grep part: `dmidecode | sed -n 's/Address: //p'`

Comment: Alright, the space has been rid of, now i'm just getting a '?' right before the name. So its "`?0xE0000.txt`". I decided to use awk instead of grep, dont think that made a difference since they practically do the same thing.

Comment: Finally! the name is now 0xE0000.txt. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: I had 1 more question, what does the "^.*" and ".*0x/0x/p" before and affter `Address:` do? And if possible, post a link to where i can learn more about this?